# Using proximity sensor in the background

Tags: ios, multitasking, proximity, uidevice

While the app is open, everything works 100%. But as soon as the app closes, the proximity sensor stops too. I've checked everywhere and this is all I've got.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Initiates the proximity sensor
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] proximityState];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(proximityStateDidChange) name:UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    //Background notification
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
}

-(void)applicationDidEnterBackground{
    NSLog(@"Entered background state.");
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setProximityMonitoringEnabled:YES];
}
```

When the app is closed it does print out "Entered background state." but doesn't keep monitoring the proximity sensor.

Comment: You can try the background task identifier hope it may work but up to 10 minutes I think.

Comment: Vectorquake:- are you able to fix it?

Comment: Any lead to this problem?